# how to slice a string dynamically?

Tags: python

I'd like keep the first few characters of a string using a[:-3] etc. But I'd like to keep this -3 as a variable, so it could be a[:-1] so I will use a variable to dynamically slice the string using a[:-b], However, to use this format, how to keep all the characters like using a[:]?  I don't want to use a[:len(a)] because I am passing this variable into a function where slcing is done. so I don't know string a outside the function.  Thanks

```
def slicing_string(slice_variable):
    a='mytext'
    return a[:slice_variable]
b=slicing_string(-3)
b
```

How to keep all the character using this function without knowning string a

Comment: I'm confused, you'd "like keep the first few characters" _and_ you want to know "how to keep all the characters"? Are you're asking how to write this function so that it can both slice "some range" as well as "the full string" depending on what `slice_variable` is?

Comment: You could show one or two examples of call and desired result of the function.

Comment: The code in question works as described, so I'm not really sure what the question is here. Caller can use `slice_variable = None` to get "everything".

Comment: You could also simply take a [slice object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#slice) as input and let the user pass whatever they want in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass in `None` to make the slice go all the way to the end of the string as if there were nothing specified at all in that part of the slice expression:

```
>>> "mytext"[:None]
'mytext'
```

This works for all parts of the slice, of course:

```
>>> "mytext"[None:None:None]
'mytext'
>>> "mytext"[None:None:-1]
'txetym'
```

When you use the slice syntax with the subscript operator, what's happening under the covers is the construction of a `slice` object with the `:` separated expressions as parameters, and the slice object is what gets passed to the `__getitem__` method; the constructor's default parameters are `None` so you can pass `None` explicitly as part of a slice and it's exactly as if you'd passed nothing.

```
>>> "mytext".__getitem__(slice(None, None, -1))
'txetym'
>>> "mytext"[slice(None, None, -1)]
'txetym'
>>> "mytext"[::-1]
'txetym'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def slicing_string(slice_variable):
    a='mytext'
    return a[:slice_variable] if slice_variable else a[:]
b=slicing_string(-3)
print(b)
b=slicing_string(None)
print(b)
```

To keep it simple:
When `slice_variable` is `None`, `a[:slice_variable]` becomes `a[:]`, which is equivalent to `a[0:len(a)]` and returns all characters of the string `a`.